# cURL response is 200, but it doesn't really post the values

Tags: php, post, curl

I have the following code for cURL using PHP;

```
$product_id_edit="Playful Minds (1062)";
$item_description_edit="TEST";
$rank_edit="0";
$price_type_edit="2";
$price_value_edit="473";
$price_previous_value_edit="473";
$active_edit="1";
$platform_edit="ios";

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://www.domain.com/adm_test/phpgen/offline_items.php?operation=insert';
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1';

$fields = array(
   'product_id_edit'=>urlencode($product_id_edit),
   'item_description_edit'=>urlencode($item_description_edit),
   'rank_edit'=>urlencode($rank_edit),
   'price_type_edit'=>urlencode($price_type_edit),
   'price_value_edit'=>urlencode($price_value_edit),
   'price_previous_value_edit'=>urlencode($price_previous_value_edit),
   'active_edit'=>urlencode($active_edit),
   'platform_edit'=>urlencode($platform_edit)
);

$fields_string="";

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
//add useragent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
print "" . curl_error($ch);
}else{
//print_r($result);
}

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//echo "HTTP Response Code: " . curl_error($ch);
echo $httpCode;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I have $httpCode printed; I get the code 200; I presume this is OK as I have read in the Manual Pages, however, when I check against the site, the POSTed values does not exist,

does this have something to do with cross-domains as I am not posting it on the same domain?, I'm doing it on 127.0.0.1/site/scrpt.php but how do I get the response code 200 if its not successful?

I also tried to get a 404 which I did by removing a part on the request URL it did return a 404 (this means that cURL is working properly in my assumption)

Does having the url https://www.domain.com/adm_test/phpgen/offline_items.php?operation=insert with the "?operation=insert" has something to do with it?

Let's presume(tho not implied), I'm from another site and I want post values into the form of another website sort'a a robot. tho my objective does not imply any evil intentions, is it that I have to encode thousand lines of info if this is not doable.

Likewise, I don't need a response from the server (but if one is available, then its just fine)

Comment: Why have you tagged this with javascript and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The operation should be passed with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Along with other paramters.

Cross-domain issue happens in case of browser. And your code seems to be a php server side code so this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the solution or the problem is different, but this line:

```
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
```

Should be this:

```
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
```

`CURLOPT_POST` - boolean, it's not a count of values, it's use post flag.

Code 200 indicates that the connection is set up correctly and received a response from the server, but it does not mean that the requested action has been implemented.

Print `$result` after request to see the response from a web server.

Comment: I get http://127.0.0.1/xampp/ as a response result which displays my local xampp home page, is that correct? Checking against the website the POST values did not push thru.